# Using PHP force download for all files

Tags: php

My question is, is there a way to use the header download PHP method for all files type;

```
    <?php

$fileid = $_GET['fid'];
$filename = $_GET['fn'];
 $auth_code = $_GET['dlauth'];
$folder = $_GET['fi'];
echo $file = $folder."/".$filename;

if (empty($fileid) || empty($filename) || empty($auth_code) || empty($folder)) {

    echo "Malformed ID, please go back and try to download again";

    } else {

        if (strlen($auth_code) > 25) {

            echo "Download session has expired or is malforned";

            }  else {






  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");

  readfile($file);





                }



        }

?>
```

Because this downloads zipped files etc, perfectly fine. However when it comes to anything else, it just corrupts.

Anyone got any clues without using switch statements to detirmine the content type with file extensions.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are doing should never corrupt any files.  Can you show an instance of corruption, i.e. a difference between the source and output files?

Comment: I made an edit in my initial post, that is the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to do it with PHP? If not, then I'd advise using a `.htaccess` to deal with this:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Otherwise, I'd advise just setting the `Content-Type` to whatever your file type is.

Comment: I use code like this, but with images, pdf etc, it still downloads corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

should be enough to force downloads on unencrypted connections. Set the `Content-Type` as you would normally do (e. g. `image/jpeg`). The rest should not be necessary or set by your webserver as needed.

Comment: It's weird, everything like pdf, images, ppt files corrupt once downloaded, stuff like mp3 and zips don't. Any idea why?

Comment: Is this the complete code? Are there any unwanted spaces before or after?

Comment: You should use application/octect-stream or whatever it is. If you use the type of file it is, if it is an image, the browser will display it

Comment: @ColeJohnson For pdf it definetely works for application/pdf as long as you tell the browser to use it as attachement.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with the file info extension.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php